# Convergence test for three improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I want to check if the following improper integrals converge or not. I each integral I wrote my approach.

- $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t+\sin^2t}{t^3}\, dt}$ :

We have that $$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t+\sin^2t}{t^3}\, dt=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{t^3}\, dt+\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^3}\, dt$$

For the first integral: \begin{align*}\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln t}{t^3}\, dt&=\int_1^{+\infty}\ln t\cdot t^{-3}\, dt=\int_1^{+\infty}\ln t\cdot \left (\frac{t^{-2}}{-2}\right )'\, dt\\ & =\left [\frac{\ln t\cdot t^{-2}}{2}\right ]_1^{+\infty}-\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t}\cdot \frac{t^{-2}}{-2}\, dt=\left [\frac{\ln t\cdot t^{-2}}{2}\right ]_1^{+\infty}+\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2t^3}\, dt\\ & =\left [\frac{\ln t\cdot t^{-2}}{2}\right ]_1^{+\infty}-\left [\frac{1}{4t^2}\right ]_1^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\ln t}{t^2}+\frac{1}{4}\\ & =\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{t}}{2t}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{2t^2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\end{align*}
For the second integral: $$\left |\frac{\sin^2t}{t^3}\right |\leq \frac{1}{t^3} \ \text{ and } \ \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t^3}\, dt=\left [-\frac{1}{2t^2}\right ]_1^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$$ From the comparison test the integral $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^3}\, dt$ and so does also the original one. Is everything correct?

- $\displaystyle{\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{t^2\ln t}{(1+t^2)^2}\, dt}$ :

$$\left |\frac{t^2\ln t}{(1+t^2)^2}\right |\leq \frac{t^2\cdot t^{0.5}}{t^4}=\frac{t^{2.5}}{t^4}=t^{-1.5}$$ But this integral doesn't converge at $t=0$, does it?

- $\displaystyle{\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\left (\ln t\right )^a}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \ a\in \mathbb{R}}$ :

Do we have to take here cases for $a$, if it is positive or negative?

Comment: Your work is valid, and probably excessive, to show that the first integral does indeed exist. The integral over the domain including $t=0$ should be fine as $\lim_{t\to 0}t^2 \ln t=0$. However your method is wrong as $| \ln t | \le t^{\frac{1}{2}}$ does not always hold when $t<1$.

Comment: Do we maybe split the integral on $(0,1)$ and in $(1,+\infty)$ ? Or what do we have to so here? @tomasliam

Comment: Yes, but everythin will be fine on $(0,1)$ as the integrand is a bounded function. Just say that its less than its maximum (with absolute values of course as the integrand has a minimum in $(0,1)$). Plots always help

Comment: Ok, thanks !! :-) @epiliam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct, but its much easier to just use $\ln t +\sin^2 t < t-1 +1 = t$.

For the second, you should distinguish the region near 0. For $t>1$, your estimate is correct and enough. For $0<t<1$, you can use $|\log t| < 1/t$.

For the third, you can show that $\ln t \le C_a t^{\frac1{3a}}$ for every $a>0$ (it follows directly from taking $\ln$s of $r<e^r$ and setting $r=t^{\frac1{3a}}$). If $a= 0$ instead, it should be obvious. For $a<0$, the behavior at infinity is very nice, but since $\log 1=0$, you have a singularity at $t=1$. Since $\ln t = t -1 + O((t-1)^2)$, then $(\log t)^a$ has a singularity like $\frac1{(t-1)^{|a|}}$ at $t=1$. You will therefore need $a>-1$ to have convergence. The integral will diverge for $a\le -1$.

Comment: To get the inequality $\ln t \le C_a t^{\frac1{3a}}$ do we have to write the power series of $\ln t$ ? What do we get if $a\leq 0$ ?

Comment: Ahh I see! And how do we choose $s$ ? With which criteria?

Comment: So we have that $$\frac{\left (\ln t\right )^a}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}\leq \frac{\left (\frac{t^s}{s}\right )^a}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{t^{sa}}{s^at^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{t^{sa-3/2}}{s^a}$$ and we want that the integral of $\frac{t^{sa-3/2}}{s^a}$ converges. The undefinite integral is $\frac{t^{sa-3/2+1}}{s^a(sa-3/2+1)}$. So that this converges on $[1, +\infty)$ it must hold that $sa-3/2+1<0$, right?

Comment: Yes, and  $s$ is a  parameter that you can choose to be as small as you wish. You got there in the end :) @MaryStar

Comment: Could you explain to me why $\log^at$ has a singularity like $\frac{1}{(t-1)^{|a|}}$ at $t=1$ ? I got stuck right now.

Comment: I don't see how we conclude that $a$ must be greater than $-1$ for convergence. Could you explain that further to me?

Comment: @MaryStar its just like $$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t^a}$$here you directly compute and see you need $a>-1$. The exact calculation is different, but the result remains the same.

Comment: Ok, thank you!! :-)